# Adding up exam scores from a column

Tags: r

If I have a data frame with a column such as:

```
math <- c(10,63,63,100,90)
```

how would I add up how many 63's are in this? Would I use unique()?

Comment: sum(math == 63)

Comment: `table(math)['63']` would also do the trick. If you dont want the names use `table(math)[['63']]`